# How to do the processing after showing the Windows Dialog?

Tags: c#, windows, dialog

I have a `tabpage` user control and 3 property pages for the `tabpage` user control which are assigned dynamically. This tabpage control is being shown inside the dialog.

The processing and filtering of data for the tabpage control is taking more time and this is resulting in a busy icon shown for more than 10 seconds before opening the Dialog.

I would like to show an empty `Dialog` opened and show the busy icon while the processing and filtering of data is done and finally shows inside the `Dialog`.

This is basically changing the order of processing.

However, I am not able to achieve this, and once the dialog is opened it waits for the user input and after giving the input only it goes to the next line. (as observed during debugging).

In the code below, the line `MnemonicSelector.InitializeMnemonicSelectorParameters(parameters);` 
is responsible for the processing and moving that after the showdialog is resulting in object not found action when the user clicks on any item inside the property page under the dialog.

```
public override MnemonicSelectorResult ShowMnemonicSelector(MnemonicSelectorSearchParameters parameters)
{
    MnemonicSelector.InitializeMnemonicSelectorParameters(parameters);
    ResizeMnemonicSelectorIfNeeded();
    SetupMnemonicDialog(m_PropertyDialog, MnemonicSelector, MnemonicSelector.Title);

    DialogResult dResult = ShowFakeDialog(m_PropertyDialog, MnemonicSelector.Title);
    return MnemonicSelector.Result;
}
private void ResizeMnemonicSelectorIfNeeded()
{
    if ((MnemonicSelector.ClientSize.Width < 909) || (MnemonicSelector.ClientSize.Height < 620))
        m_PropertyDialog.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(939, 697);
}
protected void SetupMnemonicDialog(PropertiesDialogControl propertydialog, PropertyPage page, string title)
{
    List<PropertyPage> pages = new List<PropertyPage>();
    pages.Insert(0, page);
    PropertyPage[] propertyPages = pages.ToArray();

    if (title != null)
        propertydialog.Text = title;

    propertydialog.SetPropertyPages(new List<PropertyPage>(propertyPages));
}
public virtual DialogResult ShowFakeDialog(Control contents, string title)
{
    return ShowFakeDialog(contents, title, false, "");
}

public DialogResult ShowFakeDialog(Control contents, string title, bool isCancelButtonVisible, string cancelButtonText)
{
    FakeDialog fakeDialog = new FakeDialog(this, contents, title, isCancelButtonVisible, cancelButtonText);
    using (fakeDialog)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            FakeDialog previousFakeDialog = _activeFakeDialog;
            _activeFakeDialog = fakeDialog;

            try
            {
                return fakeDialog.ShowDialog();
            }
            finally
            {
                _activeFakeDialog = previousFakeDialog;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please advice on on I can achieve the desired functionality wherein, I can show the dialog and load the property pages (processing) later.

Comment: Showing a dialog that won't be usable for another 10 seconds is not helpful to the user.  Use a BackgroundWorker to get the data so the UI doesn't freeze.  Display a litte "I'm working on it, not dead" window while it runs with an animation like a progress bar in marquee mode.  Close that window and display the dialog in the RunWorkerCompleted event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a background worker thread for this. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515138/form-show-intermittently-showing-the-form-in-a-thread). It should help you to use background worker to separate your progress animation from your processing logic.